# Rectangle Overlapping in IText Pdf Generating

Tags: java, pdf, itext

i tried to create rectangles as in the image, when i tried to create rectangles using coordinates the 
two rectangles are placing one after other.

Here is the code how iam creating Rectangle.

when i give coordinates for two rectangles those are generating one after other, i want them to overlap as in the image..How can i make it?

```
                PdfWriter writer= PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
                document.open();

                PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
                Rectangle rect,rect1;
                rect = new Rectangle(p1,p2,p3,p4); // CO-ORDINATES OF RECTANGLE
                rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
                cb.rectangle(rect);
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify the meaning of "can any one help how can make overlap of rectangles?"

Comment: Thanks for responding Santos, when i give coordinates for two rectangles those are generating one after other, i want them to overlap as in the image..

Comment: Makes sense. Please update the question instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: Still, it's a strange question since the answer is so simple. I'll make an example and post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the [`Rectangles`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/Rectangles) example to find out how to create a PDF that looks like [rectangles.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/rectangles.pdf):

[image]

When creating a rectangle, you need the coordinates of the lower-left corner and the upper-right corner of the rectangle. For instance:

```
float llx = 36;
float lly = 700;
float urx = 200;
float ury = 806;
```

You already know that you need a `PdfContentByte` instance to draw the first rectangle:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);
rect1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
rect1.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
rect1.setBorderWidth(1);
canvas.rectangle(rect1);
```

For clarity, I have defined a background color and I've set the border width to 1 pt.

Now when you want to add an extra rectangle that overlaps the same way as described in your question, you need to change the `llx` and `ury` value. That's elementary math. For instance:

```
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(llx + 60, lly, urx, ury - 40);
rect2.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
rect2.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
rect2.setBorderColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
rect2.setBorderWidth(0.5f);
canvas.rectangle(rect2);
```

To make sure you see the difference, I've now used another background color, and I defined 0.5 pt as the border width and white as the border color.

It doesn't get any simpler than this.