# Overlap one image over another image using iTextSharp PDF C#

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to add an image in PDF using iTextsharp which is displaying over another image.

For example : I have a gray rectangle & I want to display a black triangle over that rectangle which should be in between left & center of rectangle in position.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what u have tried.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of [Rectangle Overlapping in IText Pdf Generating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582887/rectangle-overlapping-in-itext-pdf-generating) in which two `Rectangles` are drawn that overlap. If it's really about `Image` objects, then it's also a matter of specifying the right coordinates. As @Sybren indicates: the question is not clear as long as you don't show what you've tried.